# Server Listening but not able to Connect Node

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

So I am trying to get started on a Node App. Right now I am just setting up my server. I am using Node, Express, Handlebars, and MongoDB. So, I have set up my server and it seems to be working fine. It is listening on Port 8080. But when I go to localhost://8080, I am getting an error message: "Localhost refused to connect."

I have tried to change my routing, etc and have had no luck fixing it. I am guessing that it is my router, or maybe how I am trying to render the page. You can see my server.js and routing file here:

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var mongoose = require("mongoose"); 
var methodOverride = require("method-override");



// Our scraping tools
var request = require("request");
var cheerio = require("cheerio");

// Set mongoose to leverage built in JavaScript ES6 Promises
mongoose.Promise = Promise;

// Initialize Express
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
// Use morgan and body parser with our app
// Override with POST having ?_method=DELETE
app.use(methodOverride("_method"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
extended: false
}));

// Make public a static dir
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.text());
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: "application/vnd.api+json" }));
// Database configuration with mongoose
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/week18day3mongoose");
var db = mongoose.connection;
// Show any mongoose errors

db.on("error", function(error) {
  console.log("Mongoose Error: ", error);
});

// Once logged in to the db through mongoose, log a success message
db.once("open", function() {
  console.log("Mongoose connection successful.");
});

// Set Handlebars.
var exphbs = require("express-handlebars");
app.engine("handlebars", exphbs({ defaultLayout: "main" }));
app.set("view engine", "handlebars");



app.listen(function(){
 console.log("Server is running and lisening on port: " + port);
});


require("./routes/htmlRoutes.js");
```

Here is my router:

```
var express = require("express");


module.exports = function(app) {

   router.get("/", function(error,doc){
     res.send("Hello World");
 });

}
```

You can see the entire project up to this point here: https://github.com/Bentley912/Article-Scraper

Comment: You can use the standard networking diagnostic tools to see if your server is actually accepting connections on that port, is bound to the correct interface, is not blocked by some packetfilter, etc. Additionally, for your test case, you could reduce it to an [MCVE] (i.e. take everything superfluous out. you don't need to connect to mongo to see if your server is accepting connections, etc)

Comment: So I figured out the issue. I needed to require the routes and use them with express.  
  ` var routes = require("./routes/htmlRoutes");
    app.use("/", routes);`